# query to increase price value by 15% in selected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to increase price by 15% in some rows of a table named `my_products`, based on the refresh_time of the product itself.

I don't know how to write this query, I was trying:

```
UPDATE my_products SET price = (price + 15%) WHERE refresh_time like "%2013%"
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is quite specific to one user, and may not be of widespread utility to future readers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_products SET price = (price * 1.15) WHERE refresh_time like "%2013%"
```

Just multiply the amount times 1.15. The `1` keeps the original value and the `.15` adds the additional 15%.